# What is the format of S3 lifecycle configuration?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

## My Problem

An S3 lifecycle configuration changes object storage classes. A typical usage is periodically moving objects to cheaper storage classes after a specified retention period.
I am trying to configure the lifecycle JSON input in the CLI, but I can't find any reference for the JSON file structure.

## What Have I Tried

- Read [Set Lifecycle Configurations Using the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/set-lifecycle-cli.html)
- Googled my question

## My Question

**What is the lifecycle JSON file structure, and how can I test or build it online?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON syntax for `--lifecycle-configuration` is:

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Date": timestamp,
        "Days": integer,
        "ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker": true|false
      },
      "ID": "string",
      "Prefix": "string",
      "Status": "Enabled"|"Disabled",
      "Transition": {
        "Date": timestamp,
        "Days": integer,
        "StorageClass": "GLACIER"|"STANDARD_IA"|"ONEZONE_IA"|"INTELLIGENT_TIERING"|"DEEP_ARCHIVE"
      },
      "NoncurrentVersionTransition": {
        "NoncurrentDays": integer,
        "StorageClass": "GLACIER"|"STANDARD_IA"|"ONEZONE_IA"|"INTELLIGENT_TIERING"|"DEEP_ARCHIVE"
      },
      "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
        "NoncurrentDays": integer
      },
      "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
        "DaysAfterInitiation": integer
      }
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

The reference below has several examples of its usage.  The reference stated in the question also has a JSON example.

**References**

[s3api put-bucket-lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle.html)